# Lorentz equations and Mathematica

Tags: calculus

Assume the Lorentz differential equations $\frac{dx}{dt} = s ( y - x ), \frac{dy}{dt} = x ( r - z )-y, \frac{dz}{dt} = x y - b z$ (parameters $s, r, b$). I am trying to use Mathematica to answer the following questions. Any help?

(a) Using the Solve command, find the equilibrium points of the system.
(b) Calculate with Mathematica, the Jacobian matrix of the system at each of the equilibrium points you found from previous question
(c) I have to calculate with Mathematica, using the command CharacteristicPolynomial, the characteristic polynomial of the Jacobian matrix, at each of the equilibrium points of (a). The polynomial is third degree, and its solutions give the Jacobian matrix eigenvalues ​​for each equilibrium point.
(d) Assume the values ​​of the parameters $ b = \frac{8}{3}, r = 28, s = 10.$ For these parameter values, calculate the roots of the characteristic polynomial you constructed in (c), that is, the eigenvalues ​​corresponding to at every point of equilibrium. Verify the roots by directly calculating the Eigenvalues ​​of the Jacobian matrix eigenvalues ​​at each equilibrium point for the given parameter values.

Comment: This kind of question is better handled at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oops, I didn't know

Comment: read the documentation first and at least try